# Clear vim register, but still able to paste

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I wanted to yank all matching lines of a buffer in a give register. I choose "A

```
:g/<match>/y A
```

did this trick for me.I guess

```
"Ap
```

is the command to paste A's content, I got my matching lines plus older lines as well, tried clearing A using

```
:let @A=''
```

but still able to paste using "Ap .What am I doing wrong?

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 16 2013 20:39:23)
MS-Windows 64-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-52
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:let @a=''
```

a is the real name of the register

A is just a way of appending to a

```
:let @A=''
```

appends nothing to register a i.e. has no effect (this explanation added later)

```
:let @A='fred'      appends fred to a
:let @A=@b          appends register b to register a
```

Comment: yes, this did it. "real name" argument makes sense too. So why did ViM not issue error/warning? does it treat A as one more variable?

Comment: Don't know but the sad thing is there's no way to append to the * paste register. you have to do :let @*=@a

Answer (score 5):

you should do

```
 let @a=''
```

usually when I need clear a reg, I do `qaq`, I feel it is easier to type.